# How can i import a function into class of an external file? NameError: name 'clicked' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, module

If i click on the checkbox, i get this error:

```
 command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
NameError: name 'clicked' is not defined
```

because the checkbox is in the external file and requires `command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))`. I need the code setup to stay like mine, i.e. with the function `clicked` in the main file and not in `page1`, and and the use of variuous lambda.

I've tried importing `clicked` (as a parameter) in several ways, such as adding it into `def __init__`, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix? Thank you

**Main file**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from page1 import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x320')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='ws', background='white', tabmargins=0)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
page1 = Page1(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='Page 1', compound='left')

datalist = []
        
def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        datalist.append(func())
    else:
        datalist.remove(func())

def try_print():
    if len(datalist) > 0:
        print("ok")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command= try_print())
button.place(x=60, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

**Page1 file**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()

        def Button1_func():
            x = "test"
            return x
  
        Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                 bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", highlightthickness = 0,
                                 command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
        Button1.place(x=10, y=30)
```

Comment: You don’t need the features of `lambda`, so I recommend as a first step creating a proper function. A function is much easier to write, read, and debug than a complex `lambda`

Comment: @BryanOakley your comment didn't help me. thanks anyway

Comment: The `clicked` error is due to it not existing in Page1 file. Cut `datalist`, `clicked` and `try_print` from Main and paste them into Page1.

Comment: You can pass `clicked` function as an argument when creating instance of `Page1` like `Page1(nb, clicked)`.  And you need to change the `Page1.__init__()` to accept this extra argument.

Comment: @acw1668 Page1(nb, clicked) ok, i understood this. I didn't understand instead what I have to change where you talk about Page1.__init__(). Can you be more clear when you talk about Page1.__init__()? What changes should I make in Page1.__init__()? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more easier to pass `clicked` function to `Page1` as an argument:

##### Main file:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from page1 import Page1

def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        datalist.append(func())
    else:
        datalist.remove(func())
    print(datalist)

def try_print():
    if len(datalist) > 0:
        print("ok")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('480x320')

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('default')
style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='ws', background='white', tabmargins=0)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

page1 = Page1(nb, clicked) # pass clicked as an argument
nb.add(page1, text='Page 1', compound='left')

datalist = []

button = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command=try_print)
button.place(x=60, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

###### page1 file

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Page1(tk.Frame):
    # added clicked argument
    def __init__(self, master, clicked, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()

        def Button1_func():
            x = "test"
            return x
  
        Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Checkbox1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                                 bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", highlightthickness = 0,
                                 command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
        Button1.place(x=10, y=30)
```

Comment: Applying your code, now I get this error: command= lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
TypeError: Page1.__init__.<locals>.clicked() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given. Why?

Comment: It works for me, so check clearly you have same changes on your code.

Comment: Yes, a little distraction of mine. Writing code when you're tired, at night, leads to distractions. Your code is great. Thanks for your help. I've upvoted and accepted the answer